# How to instantiate classes that depend on each other?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have a `PlayoffCreator` class to create playoff matches. This class has a `Bracket` instance which generates the structure of the bracket, and each match in this structure is a `Node`, made up of two instances of the class `Element`.

Then the `PlayoffCreator` goes through each `Node` the `Bracket` has and processes it, creating the match and doing other necessary operations. When processing a `Node`, both `Element`s are processed: this `Element` class has multiple subclasses and each define a different `process()` behavior.

The problem is a `Node` is instantiated by passing two `Element`s:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, bracket, home_element, away_element):
        pass
```

But an `Element` is also instantiated by passing a `Node`, because the `process()` method acts on data found both in `Bracket` and `PlayoffCreator`, both accessible through the `Node`.

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, node):
        pass
```

How does one usually deal with this circular dependency on instantiation issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities.

**1 - Instantiate the two elements, then setup the dependency**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = None

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None

a = A()
b = B()
a.b = b
b.a = a
```

You can push this further by adding a `b` optional parameter in `A`'s constructor, that defaults to `None`, and doing the same for `B`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b=None):
        self.b = b

class B:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a
```

This allows you to instantiate the second by passing the first's instance:

```
a = A()
b = B(a)
a.b = b
```

**2 - Instantiate `B` at `A` instantiation, then get that instance**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(self)

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A()
b = a.b
```

---

Both method have their advantages and drawbacks.
I would prefer n°1, for it's more flexible, because symmetrical.
However, if there is a logical hierarchy between the two classes, n°2 might be used as well.